# How to exclude .nuget packages from push in VSTS's new NuGet task?

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

AFAIK, previous NuGet task allowed, for example, `-:**/*.symbols.nupkg` - a negative pattern to exclude packages from publishing. However, that does not work with the new NuGet task.

How do I exclude my symbols and test packages from publishing to the same repository? (note, that NuGet already automatically publishes symbols packages to https://nuget.smbsrc.net anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your build definition and set `NuGet.UseLegacyFindFiles` variable to `true` in **Variables** tab.

Path to NuGet package(s) to publish:

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg;-:$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.symbols.nupkg
```

Otherwise, using

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.symbols.nupkg
```

Comment: So, basically, I just need "!" in front of exclude mask?